# Thesis frontispiece

Tags: thesis, textpos, frontespizio

I would like to write my graduation thesis in LaTeX, but I need to make a frontispiece that exactly looks like this one made with Microsoft Word:

[image: template]

I've tried the package `frontespizio` but I am not able to exactly replicate the original template. How can I place (for example) "Università degli Studi di Napoli Federico II" at that particular position?

Comment: Could you show what you tried?

Comment: Welcome! If it must look exactly like that, print it to PDF and the include it using `pdfpages`. There's no point recreating it in LaTeX just in order to produce an exactly similar copy.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Then edit it in Word or LibreOffice first. If the aim is simply to reproduce Word's typography, why copy it into LaTeX? It is different when you have a document and somebody demand you make it look like Word. Then the point is to avoid redoing it. Here, the work is done. The strategy should be the same: why redo it?

Comment: [How to design my own titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280)

Comment: Amplifying @cfr's point, I think that most commercially published/printed books will have the cover produced by an entirely separate process from the content. If you write the content in LaTeX then it'll look better, but the cover will look sufficiently like everyone else's to pass the administrators! (@cfr might consider making this an answer – sometimes ‘don't do that’ can be good advice)

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I tried as @cfr suggested and it works pretty well. I managed to reproduce the page margins by eyeball and the result is pretty ok to me!

Comment: @cfr Anything reasonable to do here?

Comment: @Johannes_B An answer saying 'use Word'? Here? Really? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Don't repaint the Mona Lisa. And don't redo what is already done.

If it needs to look like something in Word and somebody has given you said thing in Word and you have a copy of Word, go with that. Redo it in LaTeX if you want it to look better. Institutions rarely permit this and there is no point reproducing a document in another programme if it has to look identical to the copy you already have.

This does not mean you can't write your thesis in LaTeX. Just don't do the cover that way. Do that in Word. Print/export to PDF. use `pdfpages` to include it in your thesis.

If, like me, you don't have Word or if you don't want to use Word, use LibreOffice or OpenOffice or your favourite drop-in replacement instead.

Comment: Perfectly fine answer, +1. Thanks